# Trying to merge alternate column data into 1 column and then create a proper dataset

Tags: powerquery

I have a data set that is currently tabulated like this. Currently there are only 3 columns worth of data but could extend to 6 or more.

[image]

The expected result is supposed to be something like this.

[image]

I have tried to unpivot, pivot, fill right then massaging the data from there but failed.

I also tried massaging the data using the list method but i'm abit inexperienced in that aspect.

Hoping to see if there's anybody who can help me

Comment: Paste your sample data as copiable text

Comment: Did any of these answers work for you? If so please toggle checkmark next to that answer to mark issue solved

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, it should work with any number of columns, any number of blanks between values, any number of rows, and any column names for the values.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    // Rename 2nd column
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(Source,{{ Table.ColumnNames(Source){1}, "Attribute"}}),
    // Add list of column values, removing blanks, and skiping first two
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "Value", each List.Skip(List.Select(Record.FieldValues(_), each _ <> null and _ <> ""), 2)),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Name", "Attribute", "Value"}),
    // Group and combine incase there are duplicates before pivoting in the next step
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Other Columns", {"Name", "Attribute"}, {{"Value", each List.Combine([Value]), type list}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Grouped Rows", List.Distinct(#"Grouped Rows"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Pivoted Column", "Custom", each Table.FromColumns({[Fruit Type], [Weight]}, {"Fruit Type", "Weight"})),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Fruit Type", "Weight"}),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Custom", {"Fruit Type", "Weight"}, {"Fruit Type", "Weight"})
in
    #"Expanded Custom"
```

**Source**

| Name | Column1 | Column12 | Column13 | Column14 | Column15 | Column16 | Column17 | Column18 | Column19 | Column20 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Fruit Stall 1 | Fruit Type | Apple |  |  | Orange |  |  | Watermelon |  |  |
| Fruit Stall 1 | Weight |  |  | 0.8843243 |  |  | 0.6652252 |  |  | 0.89429429 |
| Fruit Stall 2 | Fruit Type | Guava |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Fruit Stall 2 | Weight |  |  | 0.0311411 |  |  |  |  |  |  |

**Result**

[image]

Comment: @kchungg did this answer provide the solution you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Alternate powerquery version, works for any number of columns and rows, assumes 2 leading columns

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Name", "Column1"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
Type = Table.SelectRows(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", each ([Column1] = "Fruit Type")),
Weight = Table.SelectRows(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", each ([Column1] = "Weight")),
combined = Table.FromColumns(Table.ToColumns(Type)&{List.Last(Table.ToColumns(Weight))},{"Name","x1","x2","Fruit Type","Weight"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(combined,{"x1", "x2"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The code below will work for any number of columns, but it assumes that the data pattern is as you show:

```
Name|Types|Fruit|blank|Weight|Fruit|blank|Weight|...
```

However, this algorithm will give results even if your blank columns actually have some data in them.

[image]

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table9"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Name", type text}}),

//Select only the first two columns and also the columns with weights and types
    #"Select Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Changed Type", List.Alternate(Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"),1,2,3)),
    
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Select Columns", {"Name", "Column 1"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute", "Column 1"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Name"}, {
        {"tbl",(t)=>
            let 
                #"Split in Half" = Table.Split(t,Number.IntegerDivide(Table.RowCount(t),2)),
                #"Add Weights" = Table.FromColumns(
                    Table.ToColumns(#"Split in Half"{0})
                    & {#"Split in Half"{1}[Value]},
                    {"Name","Fruit Type","Weight"}
                )
            in 
                #"Add Weights", type table [Name=text, Fruit Type=text, Weight=number]}}),
    #"Expanded tbl" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "tbl", {"Fruit Type", "Weight"})
in
    #"Expanded tbl"
```

***Results***

[image]